# Pra que serve o * na expressão "Foo* foo = new Foo" em C++?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Estava analisando essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248703/creating-an-instance-of-class) feita no SOEN. Lá está ensinando a instanciar uma determinada classe.

Consegui entender mais ou menos como funciona, pois quando eu utilizando meu exemplo, está dando erro na hora de compilar.

```
class Pessoa {

    int idade;
    float tamanho;

};

int main()
{
     Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
}
```

Porém aparece o seguinte erro:

> error: conversion from ‘Pessoa*’ to non-scalar type ‘Pessoa’ requested
>         Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa ();

O erro é solucionado quando coloco um asterisco na frente da palavra `Pessoa`.

```
 Pessoa* pessoa = new Pessoa ();
```

Sendo assim, qual é a função do asterisco nesse caso? O que ele indica?

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, mas mereceu o -1 de alguém. Feliz 2016, rsrsrsrsrs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como foi usado o operador `new`, que é um alocador de memória no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), a única forma de se referenciar ao objeto alocado é através de um ponteiro, e o `*` é a forma de declarar uma variável dizendo que ela é um ponteiro para um tipo. O `new` sempre retorna um ponteiro. Ele é equivalente, mas mais flexível, que o [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) do C.

Então `Pessoa *` pode ser lido como "ponteiro para Pessoa". Que é bem diferente de apenas `Pessoa`. Este último teria um tamanho suficiente na variável para toda a estrutura de dados que compõe `Pessoa` mas para isto não poderia usar o `new`. No caso de `Pessoa *` precisa só o espaço para o ponteiro (4 ou 8 bytes nas plataformas mais comuns hoje em dia) na variável. Os dados serão colocados em outro lugar, por isso ele é apontado.

Lembre-se sempre que em C++ você tem que cuidar dos detalhes da memória, você não acessa ela de forma tão transparente quanto em outras linguagens. Isto dá poder, mas traz responsabilidades.

Eu sei que é só um teste, mas para classes tão pequenas é melhor alocar sem o `new`. E neste caso é melhor usar uma `struct` do que uma `class`, ainda que faça pouca diferença real, é só para deixar mais claro que é ideal alocar na *stack*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility.